# Box Whisker plot of date frequency

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, statistics

Good morning all! 
I have a Pandas df and Im trying to create a monthly box and whisker of 30 years ofdata.
[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViSXH.png)

```
         datetime   year   month day  hour  lon      lat
0  3/18/1986 10:17  1986      3   18    10 -124.835  46.540
1   6/7/1986 13:38  1986      6    7    13 -121.669  46.376
2  7/17/1986 20:56  1986      7   17    20 -122.436  48.044
3   7/26/1986 2:46  1986      7   26     2 -123.071  48.731
4   8/2/1986 19:54  1986      8    2    19 -123.654  48.480
```

Trying to see the mean amount of occurrences in X month, the median, and the max/min occurrence ( and date of max and min)..

Ive been playing around with pandas.DataFrame.groupby() but dont fully understand it.

I have grouped the date by month and day occurrences. I like this format:
Code:

```
   df = pd.read_csv(masterCSVPath)
   months = df['month']

   test = df.groupby(['month','day'])['day'].count()
   output: ---->
month   day
   1      1       50
          2      103
          3       97
          4       29
          5       60
         ...
   12     27      24
          28       7
          29      17
          30      18
          31       9
```

So how can i turn that df above into a box/whisker plot? 
The x-axis i want to be months..
y axis == occurrences

Answer (score 0):

Try this (without doing groupby):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.boxplot(x = 'month', y = 'day', data = df)
```

In case you want the months to be in Jan, Feb format then try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import datetime as dt
df['month_new'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%b')
sns.boxplot(x = 'month_new', y = 'day', data = df)
```